# AngularJS 1.6.6 ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mc1">


    <label class="control-label">Semester:</label>
    <select ng-model="selectedSemesters" ng-change="selectedSemesterChanged()" class="form-control">
        <option value="{{v.SemesterId}}" ng-repeat="v in semesters">{{v.SemesterId}}</option>
    </select>
    <script>
        var app=angular.module('myApp',[]);
        app.controller('mc1',function($scope)
        {
            $scope.semesters='[{"SemesterId":"Fall 2017"},{"SemesterId":"Spring 2017"}]';
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run this page, I get the error error: [ngRepeat:dupes]. I tried to add track by $index but it totally doesn't work.

Can anyone tell me the reason?

Edit: Sorry I didn't explain clear. I use library in C# to convert a datatable object to json string. Then pass this to the web page through web api. In the script, I use angular.jsonFrom(response.data).

And response in browser is "[{\"SemesterId\":\"Fall 2017\"},{\"SemesterId\":\"Spring 2017\"}]". I have fixed the bug but I don't know why.

Thanks all. PS. Correct answer is followed.

```
<body ng-app="mySelect" ng-controller="myCt">
    <select ng-model="mySelected1">
        <option ng-repeat="x in data1">{{x.SemesterId}}</option>
    </select>    

    <select ng-model="mySelected2" ng-options="x.SemesterId for x in data1">{{x.SemesterId}}</select>

    <label ng-model="data1"></label>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('mySelect', []);
        app.controller('myCt', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

             $scope.data1=angular.fromJson('[{\"SemesterId\":\"Fall 2017\"},{\"SemesterId\":\"Spring 2017\"}]');
        }]);

    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: For select I think it is better to use the `ng-options`



    `<select class="form-control" 
      ng-model="controller.selectedItem"
            ng-options="item as item.name for item in controller.items"></select>`

Answer (score 2):

You are passing string instead of array. So ng-repeat shows error when iterating.
Change below line;

```
$scope.semesters='[{"SemesterId":"Fall 2017"},{"SemesterId":"Spring 2017"}]';
```

To

```
$scope.semesters=[{"SemesterId":"Fall 2017"},{"SemesterId":"Spring 2017"}];
```

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Please see this Plunkr working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mc1">


    <label class="control-label">Semester:</label>
    <select ng-model="selectedSemesters" ng-change="selectedSemesterChanged()" class="form-control">
        <option value="v.SemesterId" ng-repeat="v in semesters track by $index">{{v.SemesterId}}</option>
    </select>
    <script>
        var app=angular.module('myApp',[]);
        app.controller('mc1',function($scope)
        {
            $scope.semesters=[{"SemesterId":"Fall 2017"},{"SemesterId":"Spring 2017"}];
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

https://jsbin.com/fuvihatihi/1/edit?html,output

There was nothing to *repeat* in your `semester` variable, because there was quotes around array declaration.